# Pureftpd-upload while uploading image through ftp

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to upload image from one server to another server through FTP by using PHP.But the uploaded data shows.pureftpdupload.5809ed2f.15.7b36.24316ca6 error. 
I am using this code.

```
    $connection = 'servername';
    $username = 'xxxx';
    $password = 'yyyy';
    $local_file = 'http://servername/test.jpg';
    $remote_file = 'admin/files/company/test.jpg';
    $connection = ftp_connect($server);

    if (@ftp_login($connection, $username, $password)) {
        // successfully connected
        //echo 'connected';exit;
    } else {
        echo 'not connected';
        return false;
    }
    if (ftp_put($connection, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
     echo "successfully uploaded\n";
    } else {
     echo "There was a problem while uploading \n";
    }
```

Comment: What does it mean *"uploaded data shows.pureftpdupload.5809ed2f.15.7b36.24316ca6 error"*?

Comment: when upload to other server,the uploaded file showing like this.i think temporary upload file.

Comment: Do you mean that after your upload code finishes, the destination folder (when viewed in some FTP client) shows the `.pureftpdupload.5809ed2f.15.7b36.24316ca6` file instead of the file you uploaded?

Comment: yes the uploaded file name is .pureftpdupload.5809ed2f.15.7b36.24316ca6

Comment: But actually i uploaded the image.

Comment: And if you upload the image using a standalone FTP client?

Comment: By manually i can able to upload the image in FTP.

Comment: And did you try to upload a real local file?

Comment: yes i am uploading image from one server image path to another server.

Comment: No you are uploading a file from HTTP server: `http://servername/test.jpg`. Try a real local path.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want to upload a local file from a web server. But by mistake or misunderstanding, you are using file's HTTP URL (`http://servername/test.jpg`) instead of file's local path.

Try to use a real local path, like `/home/user/test.jpg`.

This may work as a generic solution: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/test.jpg"`

Comment: The issues is when we upload through FTP,we need to give permission for that destination image path with image name.